# Add values to dropdown list programatically at run time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to change the list item values of a dropdown list based on values of an other dropdown list. The list values of drpAdult range from 0-9 and list values of drpInfant range from 0-(Value of drpAdult selected).

So, for example, if I select 5 in the drpAdult dropdown, the range of list item values of drpInfant will be from 0-5.

I have written the code below, but it is not populating the values in the drpInfant dropdown, which I am trying to insert on drpAdult_SelectedIndexChanged event.

```
Protected Sub drpAdult_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, 
 ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles drpAdult.SelectedIndexChanged  

    Dim count As Integer    
    count = drpAdult.Items.Count
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
     While count > 0
        i = i + 1

        drpInfant.Items.Add(New ListItem(i, i))
        count = count - 1

    End While
End Sub
```

What might cause this problem, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Please specify _"my code below is not working"_ What does that mean?

Comment: I mean to say, it is not populating values in drpInfant dropdown which I am trying to insert on drpAdult_SelectedIndexChanged event

Comment: Thanks Andeas, it surely is VB.net

Comment: Is it an ajax request (update panel) by any chance?
When do you bind your drop down initially (page load, page prerender? Do you bind it with initial values only if it is not a postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what *"is not working"* means, but this seems to be easier anyway:

```
Dim newCount = drpAdult.Items.Count + 1
For i As Int32 = 0 To newCount
    Dim newItem As New ListItem(i.ToString, i.ToString)
    drpInfant.Items.Add(newItem)
Next
```

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody: Have you used the debugger to see what happens? Are you databinding one or both dropdownlists in page_load before this event is triggered? Is this event triggered at all(set a breakpoint there)?

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody: Then i assume that you databind `drpAdult` in `Page_Load` even on postbacks. That will prevent events from being triggered. Surround the databinding with `If Not IsPostBack Then ...`

Comment: IT worked, Auto Postback was false for drpAdult, I changed that to true, it will worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines...

```
drpInfant.Items.Clear()
dim n as Integer
Integer.TryParse(drpAdult.SelectedValue, n)

For i as integer = 1 to n
  if n < i Then Exit For 'it's not fun when this condition happens in VB
  drpInfant.Items.Add(New ListItem(i, i))
Next
```

Comment: I tried this also, but still no change. Initially , drpInfant has two list items already as 0 and 1. If they get overwrited, it doesnot matter provided I get values based on selected value of drpAdult

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I have tested this & working fine:

```
    Protected Sub drpAdult_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    drpInfant.Items.Clear()

    Dim count As Integer = drpAdult.SelectedIndex
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    While count >= 0
        drpInfant.Items.Add(New ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()))

        i = i + 1
        count = count - 1
    End While
End Sub
```